# When are http requests blocking Angular rendering?

Tags: angular

I have a list of components (simple `*ngFor`), each using another component that gets a username as `Input()`. That component then fetches some data, like full name and email address and if it gets it, it updates the display.

I have noticed though that the whole list component is not rendered until all of the user fetches complete. How to avoid that? I want to show the username until I get the user data(, if I get it).

Here is an excerpt of my code:

**user.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class UserComponent extends DestroyNotifierMixin implements OnInit {
  private _user: User;
  @Input() set user(user: User) {
    this._user = user.pk ? user : new User((user as unknown) as string);
  }

  get user(): User {
    return this._user;
  }

  constructor(private users: UserApiService, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.user.email === undefined) { // means we do not have the full user info
      this.users
        .retrieve$(this.user.pk)         // fetches user info based on username (primary key)
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed))
        .subscribe((user) => {
          this.user = user;
          this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        });
    }
  }
}
```

**user.component.html**

```html
<span
  >{{ user.displayName }}
  <a
    *ngIf="user.email"
    href="https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users={{ user.email }}"
    target="_blank"
  >
    <mat-icon>chat</mat-icon>
  </a>
</span>
```

**user.model.ts**

```js
export class User {
  constructor(
    public username: string,
    public email?: string,
    public givenName?: string,
    public familyName?: string
  ) { }

  get displayName(): string {
    return this.familyName && this.givenName
      ? `${this.familyName}, ${this.givenName}`
      : this.username;
  }

  get pk() {
    return this.username;
  }

  toString(): string {
    return this.username;
  }
}
```

How can I debug this? Shall I use an other hook than init hook for this? Maybe the problem is the `detectChanges()` call, if it gets called too frequently from multiple of components? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you add some of the view template code?

Comment: I have added the template and some code for the user model. Nothing fancy, no `async` pipe, it just calls a property of the user model.